# how to add double zero after a number in php?

Tags: php, string

I am new on php and try to convert a array value by adding zero in number format.
here is my number array value: 2530

I want to convert to 2,530.00

how to i do this in php?

Comment: This sounds more like you want to *format* the number rather than *convert* it, in which case you want something like [PHP number formatting](http://php.net/number_format).

Answer (score 6):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format):

```
echo number_format('2530', 2);
```

**Note:** `number_format()` accepts additional parameters, but in your case the default comma separator and decimal point will work.